# Parameter x of constructor in ... required a bean of type '...' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, web, mapstruct, httpbackend

I am working on a personal project with Spring Boot. I am getting the following error:

> Parameter 2 of constructor in com.learningapp.backend.AcademixHub.services.UserService required a bean of type 'com.learningapp.backend.AcademixHub.mappers.UserMapper' that could not be found.

Here is the code of `UserService.java`:

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
     private final UserRepository userRepository; 

        private final  PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        private final UserMapper userMapper;    
        
        
    
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserMapper userMapper) {
            super();
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
            this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
            this.userMapper = userMapper;
        }


     public UserDto register(SignUpDto signupDto) {
         System.out.println("hello man hi hello");
            Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByEmail(signupDto.getEmail());

            if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
                throw new AppException("Login already exists", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            User user = userMapper.signUpToUser(signupDto);
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(signupDto.getPassword()));

            User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

            return userMapper.toUserDto(savedUser);
        }
     
     public UserDto login(LoginDto loginDto) {
            User user = userRepository.findByEmail(loginDto.getEmail())
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("Unknown user", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));

            if (passwordEncoder.matches(loginDto.getPassword(), user.getPassword())) {
                return userMapper.toUserDto(user);
            }
            throw new AppException("Invalid password", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }


        public UserDto findByEmail(String login) {
            User user = userRepository.findByEmail(login)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("Unknown user", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
            return userMapper.toUserDto(user);
        }

}
```

Here is the code of `UserMapper.java`:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
@Component
public interface UserMapper {
    
    UserDto toUserDto(User user);
    
    @Mapping(target = "password", ignore = true)
    User signUpToUser(SignUpDto signUpDto);
    
}
```

If I remove `final` from those three variables and add a default constructor, the server runs properly. However, if I hit the register endpoint with a POST request, I get another error:

> [Request processing failed: `java.lang.NullPointerException`:
> Cannot invoke "com.learningapp.backend.AcademixHub.repository.UserRepository.findByEmail(String)" because "this.userRepository" is null] with root cause

What Should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring complains that no bean implementing `UserMapper` where found.
The most probable cause is that `UserMapperImpl` has not been generated by MapStruct annotation processor.
It should be located in the same package than `UserMapper`, but under target/generated-sources.

Do you find it after maven compilation (running `mvn compile`)?

## maven, gradle

For this implementation to be generated during compilation with maven, the annotation processing must be configured in maven pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

See https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation where you'll find this information for gradle too.

## IDE support

Mappers can also be generated during development with your IDE. See https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/

---

You can also have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct to understand how MapStruct works.

`@Component` is not needed on `UserMapper` as it will be automatically added on the `UserMapperImpl` implementation.

You are using constructor injection, which is fine, do not add a default constructor because dependencies won't be injected (all fields will remain null, causing the NullPointerException you described).

Comment: ```<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
```
where should i add it

Comment: And There is no folder or file named as generated-sources in target directory. 
It has only 2 folders classes and test-classes

Comment: this code block must be added in pom.xml

Comment: if there is no folder named as generated-sources in target directory, that's because mapstruct annotation processor has not been configured or mvn compile did not run, so mappers are not generated

Comment: Still getting the same error.
( https://github.com/AnirudhKaranth/Acadamix/tree/main/server/AcademixHub )

Comment: I just cloned your repository and ran the following test successfully
Autowired
UserService userService;
Test
void test() {
    userService.register(new SignUpDto("test", "test@test.com", "test"));
}

Comment: are you sure you did not forget to run mvn compile before running?

Comment: see sceenshot: https://github.com/AnirudhKaranth/Acadamix/issues/1, you can see UserMapperImpl has been generated and test passes

Comment: Iam running it using the run icon in eclipse.
should i run mvn compile seperatly. could you please give the steps.

Comment: First run mvn compile, then run app

Comment: It compiled correctly. The Build was success. But when i ran test it gave error:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) on project AcademixHub

Comment: https://github.com/AnirudhKaranth/Acadamix/issues/1  : I have posted the error...

BTW which is your IDE

Comment: Now the generated-sources/annotations is created but it is empty.

Comment: The problem you're now facing is related to your testing configuration, which is not related to this issue so let's discuss on github.